# My device is not listing in "choose a running device" in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 32 bit version and Redmi 2 prime phone.
I just first time opened the software and connected my phone and clicked on play button.But my device is not listing in "choose a running device" in android studio.I am just a beginner so please tell me in steps what to do.

Comment: Is USB debugging turned on on your phone? Do you need to install a drive from your manufacturer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable USB debugging in your mobile, then connect your mobile to your PC. Android studio will recognize the device by itself.

Refer [this](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) for info on enabling USB debugging.